# Function returning a Function?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm learning Javascript and trying to figure out what this `Sa() function` does in this code example.

I thought it was a Kobayashi Maru, upon further inspection I believe that this `Sa() function` returns the other functions as well as itself. Am I close?

And if that's the case, what would that accomplish?

```
var Jj, Ss, Sa;

Ss = function(n) {
  return n + 1;
};

Jj = function(f, n) {
  return function(i) {
  if (n < 1) {
  return i;
} else {
  return f(Jj(f, n - 1)(i));
  }
 };
};

Sa = function(a, b) {
  return Jj(Jj(Ss, a), b)(0);
};
```

Comment: Try running it in the JS debugger, and setting breakpoints before all the `return` statements.

Comment: Should `Jj(Sa, a)` be `Jj(Ss, a)`?

Comment: Why such cryptic function names?

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding alert("I am an alert"); before each return, i didn't get an alert. You're looking at the code as it was given to me. No idea why things are the way they are.

Comment: @wilwaldon, Call the function and add it to question. let us know what is your goal from this

Comment: @Venkat , my goal is to learn how it works, how we got to the result of a*b. I'm learning as I go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bamar noticed as well, there seems to be a typo in the original question. The `Jj(Sa, a)` should be `Jj(Ss, a)`.

With that change, the `Sa` function returns the product of `a` and `b`, but calculates it in a very circuitous way.

Here is a modified version of the (fixed) code that logs state information:

```
var Jj, Ss, Sa;

Ss = function(n) {
  console.log("C:" + (n + 1)); 
  return n + 1;
};

Jj = function(f, nIterations) {
  return function(i) {
    if (nIterations < 1) {
      console.log('A' + nIterations + ":" + i); 
      return i;
    } else {
      console.log('B' + nIterations); 
      return f(Jj(f, nIterations - 1)(i));
    }
  };
};

Sa = function(a, b) {
  return Jj(Jj(Ss, a), b)(0);
};
```

And here is the output of a sample run:

```
> Sa(3,4)
B4
B3
B2
B1
A0:0
B3
B2
B1
A0:0
C:1
C:2
C:3
B3
B2
B1
A0:3
C:4
C:5
C:6
B3
B2
B1
A0:6
C:7
C:8
C:9
B3
B2
B1
A0:9
C:10
C:11
C:12
12
```

Comment: I think you're right and there was a typo! Good catch!  I'm not sure, what does the '(0)' do?

Comment: That is the initial value. If you used, say, `3` instead, then the result will be `a*b + 3`.

Comment: If I may ask, how did you get a*b? I kinda get it, but my javascript skill is pretty basic and i think i may have jumped in a bit over my head. Thanks for all the help!